# Why does this cast work in one statement and not another?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, casting

These two queries work fine:

```
select cast(sku as bigint) from bid                 
select cast(sku as bigint) from vwbidrecords
```

This query fails with the message "Error converting data type varchar to bigint."

```
select * from bid where cast(sku as bigint) in  
(select cast(sku as bigint) from vwbidrecords)
```

Does it make sense to anyone why the 3rd wouldn't work even though the 1st two are fine?

Comment: What is the data type of `sku` field in each table? (Not that it neccessarily matters)

Comment: Not at first glance. But it also doesn't make sense to cast sku to bigint when you can compare them directly, and it doesn't make sense to use an IN clause like that instead of an inner join. Not judgin'; just sayin'.

Comment: Do the first two queries really work exactly as shown, i.e. for every row in the tables?

Comment: Can you recreate the problem with [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com)?

Comment: It can be inferred from your code that the column sku is of type varchar. Well in that case, No it makes no sense at all, unless there are some tupes in sku which cannot be converted to bigint, and in that case, any one of your first two queries must also fail.

Comment: @MikeSherrill'Catcall' Actually it does make sense because one field has leading 0's and the other does not.  And when I'm running lots of quick ad hoc queries to compare data it's faster to just cut/paste into an in clause than it is to write a join.  So thanks for not judgin' :)

Comment: @HABO Yep.  See RichardTheKiwi's answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're using a view, which I am guessing must have some multi-table JOIN involved (that filters the view to only numeric SKUs) or at least a single table with a WHERE clause.

It will also most likely involve some ISNUMERIC test in the view query.

Check out this bug [SQL Server should not raise illogical errors](http://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/537419/sql-server-should-not-raise-illogical-errors) which explains why

> Error converting data type varchar to bigint.

will be raised when you least expect it.  The fact that

```
select cast(sku as bigint) from vwbidrecords
```

on its own works only means that it is optimized differently to query 3.  Check both execution plans and it will become clearer.